# Is there a way to install latest the Spinnaker/Helm/K8s combo?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I've been using
`helm install spinnaker stable/spinnaker -f spinnaker-config.yaml --timeout 1200s --version 2.0.0-rc9`
Which is the latest helm chart for Spinnaker.
Using this on a freshly created K8s cluster on GKE.
Just installed Helm so I have the latest.

Result is that it created a Job named `spinnaker-install-using-hal` and the pod for this job keeps restarting...
Container logs show:

```
/opt/halyard/scripts/config.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

I've actually found this file is mounted from a `ConfigMap` named `*-spinnaker-halyard-config`.

The `ConfigMap` value for `config.sh` is set to:

```
# Spinnaker version
$HAL_COMMAND config version edit --version 1.19.4


# Storage



$HAL_COMMAND config storage gcs edit --project XXXXXXXXXX --json-path /opt/gcs/key.json --bucket <GCS-BUCKET-NAME>
$HAL_COMMAND config storage edit --type gcs



# Docker Registry
$HAL_COMMAND config provider docker-registry enable

if $HAL_COMMAND config provider docker-registry account get dockerhub; then
  PROVIDER_COMMAND='edit'
else
  PROVIDER_COMMAND='add'
fi

$HAL_COMMAND config provider docker-registry account $PROVIDER_COMMAND dockerhub --address index.docker.io \
   \
  --repositories library/alpine,library/ubuntu,library/centos,library/nginx

$HAL_COMMAND config provider kubernetes enable

if $HAL_COMMAND config provider kubernetes account get default; then
  PROVIDER_COMMAND='edit'
else
  PROVIDER_COMMAND='add'
fi

$HAL_COMMAND config provider kubernetes account $PROVIDER_COMMAND default --docker-registries dockerhub \
            --context default --service-account true \
             \
             \
             \
             \
            --omit-namespaces=kube-system,kube-public \
             \
             \
            --provider-version v2
$HAL_COMMAND config deploy edit --account-name default --type distributed \
                       --location default
# Use Deck to route to Gate
$HAL_COMMAND config security api edit --no-validate --override-base-url /gate
$HAL_COMMAND config features edit --artifacts true
```

In line #9 it has the value `<GCS-BUCKET-NAME>` instead of the real bucket name. This probably caused the script to fail.

Still not sure what causes that to not be populated.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem... maybe someone finds it helpful...

I was using the following guide https://medium.com/velotio-perspectives/know-everything-about-spinnaker-how-to-deploy-using-kubernetes-engine-57090881c78f

Which is a great guide but i guess not too updated...

Anyway it says you should configure

```
storageBucket: $BUCKET 
gcs:   
  enabled: true 
  project: $PROJECT   
  jsonKey: '$SA_JSON'
```

Which is incorrect... it should be as follows:

```
gcs:   
  enabled: true
  bucket: $BUCKET
  project: $PROJECT
  jsonKey: '$SA_JSON'
```

This solved it.

Comment: the official chart moves fast. i recommend using the values.yaml in the repo as your guide and then locking subsequent development by specifying the chart version you're working with to prevent future instability.

Comment: Thanks @CamiloSantana - perhaps you could suggest that to the author of the guide, might help the next person.